# Dynamic SOQL, Access Subquery Results

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, subquery

I'm having trouble understanding how to access each individual result returned from a subquery. The picture shows the code which:

1. takes fields and objects chosen by a user and assigns them to String variables,
2. the string vars are used to query a dynamic query string,
3. the query string is feed into a database.query and the result is stored in an array
4. I can individually access each of the query results from this array (parent object results),
5. But I have not been able to individually access the subquery results.

If I feed the subquery results into an array...something like:

```
SObject[] c = p.get(i).getSObjects(childO);
```

I still can't get to each individual child record per parent. I can only see all child records per each parent. I need to get to each child record per adult, so that I can roll up results.

Can anyone help?

```
// These strings will be populated dynamically from a VF page
String parentO  = 'Account';
String parentF  = 'Products_Purchased__c';
String childO   = 'Opportunity';
    if(childO  == 'Opportunity'){ childO = 'Opportunities'; }
String childF   = 'Product_Type__c';

// create dynamic SOQL query string
String query = 'SELECT id, (select ' +childF+ ' from ' +childO+') FROM ' +parentO;

// query and store 33 results in variable p
SObject[] p = Database.query(query);

for(Integer i = 0; i < p.size(); i++){
    system.debug('Parent result from SOQL query: ' +p[i]);
    if(p.get(i).getSObjects(childO) <> null){
        system.debug('Child result(s) from SOQL query: ' +p.get(i).getSObjects(childO));
        system.debug('Child field: ' +c.get(i).get(childF));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store it as a `List<SObject>` and then *iterate over that collection*.

```
List<SObject> children = parent.getSObjects('Opportunities');
for (SObject child : children)
{
    system.debug(child);
}
```

Also, **[if you want to roll up data from `Opportunity` to `Account`, you can just use a Rollup Summary Field](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BraS)**.

If you want to do fancy aggregations that aren't supported out of the box, the **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** tool almost certainly does everything you need without requiring you to write a single line of code.

Comment: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getSObjects(String) from the type List<SObject>." Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I tried that yesterday. Same result today.

Comment: The single parent would be `p.get(i)` in your example. You need to call it from a single `SObject` instance (`p[i]`), not the entire collection (`p`).

Comment: Ah, I have to use it with a nested for loop. Thanks. About the rollup field suggestion, this has to work for any object (dynamic), and perform more functionality than a standard roll-up, like be able to concatenate text fields, for instance.

Comment: You should look at the **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** tool, which almost certainly does everything you need. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: We have a paid solution called Rollup Helper in play right now, but it's giving our admin pain. I believe they'd be willing to use another program if there's no cost. The cost is the main issue. So, they tasked us with developing a tool in-house that's not packaged, and can therefore be worked on as needed.

Comment: It's free and 100% configurable. I really can't recommend strongly enough you give it a try.

Comment: I'll give it a solid look and possibly propose it to the admin after I'm familiar with it. Thanks!